# Access Show Date In MMDDYYY Format

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2013

I have a backend SQL Server 2008 R2 table linked into an Access 2013 database.  The field name is entereddate and it is is a date field type in SQL Server.  When I view the data from within SSMS it appears as a date and I just Cast it to the proper format.  However, on my access form I can not get the date to format to mmddyyyy.  I tried adding an input mask on the form field (called txtentereddate) but that is not altering the way the date is displayed.

What must I change to have the date in access dispaly as MMDDYYYY?

Comment: Are you sure when you bring up the linked table in design view, the column is indeed a date/time column? Once it is a date time then formatting on the client side should be problem free. You don't want nor need to set any formatting server side.

Comment: What is your Format property set to on your MS-Access Form `txtentereddate` control? It may not react properly if it recognizes it as a date/time field, but you can try using "MMDDYYYY" in the format property. Otherwise you might have to use a separate display control that sets the ControlSource property to `=Format([txtentereddate],"mmddyyyy")`

Comment: As @dbmitch mentiones, all you need is to set the _Format_ property of the field to: mmddyyyy

Comment: @dbmitch - if I look at the properties of the field and look under the format header, the format setting is set to short date.  Is that where I should be looking?  If I put "MMDDYYYY" in the format it still displays incorrectly

Comment: Yeah. Figured that. You can create a query out of your table by clicking on the ... Button to the right of Rowsource property. Select * for all fields then add your date field into a format statement calling it customdate. Replace your date field in the control with customdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the MS Access `format()` function:

```
format(date, "mmddyyyy")
```

Comment: Where would I place this syntax?

Comment: @PinkSmellyBlueSocks . . . In the `SELECT` statement or equivalent way that you get the columns you want to show.